# Seeking Oracle Spatial tutorials?

Tags: references, oracle-spatial

I am working on Oracle Spatial 11g and I am referring to [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/html/A88805_01/sdo_intr.htm#884908) as a learning resource.

Does any one know any more Oracle Spatial tutorials?

We want to integrate Oracle Spatial data with ArcGIS and QGIS.

Comment: Your need to learn ArcSDE too if using ArcGIS and Oracle Spatial... 10.1 can support no SDE connections - see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37125/arcsde-10-1-no-longer-needed

Comment: Another Good link for Oracle Spatial - http://spatialdbadvisor.com/oracle_spatial_tips_tricks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> This question has been converted to Community Wiki and wiki locked
>   because it is an example of a question that seeks a list of answers
>   and appears to be popular enough to protect it from closure.  It
>   should be treated as a special case and should not be viewed as the
>   type of question that is encouraged on this, or any Stack Exchange
>   site, but if you wish to contribute more content to it then feel free
>   to do so by editing this answer.

---

I suggest starting with this excellent pdf for the conceptual aspects:

- [Getting Started with Oracle Spatial by Tim Armitage](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/spatial/pdf/au_melbourne06_start.pdf)

Then move onto the dev guide (11gR2 here, about 900 pages worth):

- [Oracle® Spatial Developer's Guide 11g Release 2 (11.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11830/toc.htm)

At that point you'll be informed enough to integrate Oracle Spatial professionally into any Desktop GIS application. Specifically for ArcGIS, here's the ground rules and documentation for using SDO_Geometry within ArcSDE geodatabases:

- [How do geodatabases use Oracle Spatial?](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/How_do_geodatabases_use_Oracle_Spatial/002n0000006s000000/)